# exclude status in dropdown list

Tags: mysql, select, while-loop, where-clause

I'm trying to exclude all values where `status` is Defective in my mobo table, but this code doesn't work.

It's still showing everything in my Dropdown

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'admin2018', 'inventory') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');
    $result = $conn->query("select mobo, status FROM mobo WHERE NOT 'status = Defective'");
    echo "<select name='mobo'>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                  unset($id, $name);
                  $id = $row['mobo'];
                  $name = $row['mobo'];
                  echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

}
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind I already fix it using

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'admin2018', 'inventory') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');
    $result = $conn->query("select mobo, status FROM mobo WHERE status!='Defective'");
    echo "<select name='mobo'>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                  unset($id, $name);
                  $id = $row['mobo'];
                  $name = $row['mobo'];
                  echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

}
    echo "</select>";
?>
```